# Want to hide <div> on mouse-over, whilst allowing links behind to be active

Tags: html, css, hover

Currently I have a set of links with a div over them. I would like the div to disappear on mouseover allowing the links behind to be clickable.

```
:hover {display: none}
```

on the covering div causes a flickering effect at it's creating a loop so I can't do that.

```
:hover {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
```

also does not work as the div is still covering the links. I thought that adding a

```
:hover {pointer-events:none;}
```

could work but that also creates a flickering loop.

I basically want a div to not be there when I mouse over it, yet making it not there causes the :hover command to not read it as there, making it come back (...and the flickering begins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The reason is that `display: none` physically removes the element, meaning you are no longer hovering it.  Thus, it adds it back, and now, you're hovering it.  That's why you get the flickering effect.  `visibility: hidden` on the other hand, keeps the element exactly where it is, so you'll still technically be hovering it.

---

I lied, that is not going to work at all.

Here is a real solution:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Hello</a>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {   
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: black;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
    display: none;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqsn2fym/

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, I tried something like this and wondered why it didn't work. My problem was that my "container" was not containing, it was on the same tree level so wasn't working. Cheers, H